# Read CSV files in the same order as saved in the path, in R

Tags: r, list, csv

I have multiple CSV files that are stored in a specific order, and I want to read them in this exact same order, from the bottom to the top. They are stored like this:

```
tFile20.RAW
tFile17.RAW
tFile16.RAW
tFile12.RAW
tFile11.RAW
tFile10.RAW
.
.
```

and so on until `tFile1.RAW`. I've seen multiple questions about this issue but all of them were regarding python.

I'm using this code, but it is reading the files in a random order (the CSVs are stored in `smallfolder`):

```
temp = list.files(path = '/bigfolder/myname/smallfolder', pattern="RAW", full.names = TRUE)
final_list = lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

it's reading `tFile1.RAW` and then jumps to `tFile10.RAW` and `tFile11.RAW` and so on..

How can I make it read starting from `tFile1.RAW` and go to the top? so the first CSV file it reads would be `tFile1.RAW`, hence `final_list[[1]] = tFile1.RAW`, and then `final_list[[2]] = tFile2.RAW`, `final_list[[3]] = tFile3.RAW` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
```

Preparing the folder structure and writing files

```r
# Creating folder 
folder_path <- "bigfolder/myname/smallfolder"
dir.create(folder_path, recursive = TRUE)

# Files
files <- c("file1.csv", "file10.csv", "file11.csv", "file12.csv", "file13.csv", 
  "file14.csv", "file15.csv", "file16.csv", "file17.csv", "file18.csv", 
  "file19.csv", "file2.csv", "file20.csv", "file3.csv", "file4.csv", 
  "file5.csv", "file6.csv", "file7.csv", "file8.csv", "file9.csv"
)

# writing files
lapply(files, \(x) write.csv(x, file.path(folder_path, x)))
```

With that I have a folder structure as you described in your code, now I will
list all files I’m going to read. The only difference here is that I will use
`full.names = FALSE` because I think that in you local machine the path has numbers in it

```r
temp <- list.files(folder_path)
```

You have to sort the files afther you use the `list.file` function, I would do it as follow:

1. Extract the integer in the name of the file

```r
file_number <- stringr::str_extract(temp, "[0-9]+") |> as.numeric()
```

2. Get the position where each file should be, comparing the ordered file_number with
   the position they actually have

```r
correct_index_order <- sapply(sort(file_number), \(x) which(file_number == x))
```

3. Rearrange you `temp` vector with that new vector

```r
temp <- temp[correct_index_order]

temp
#>  [1] "file1.csv"  "file2.csv"  "file3.csv"  "file4.csv"  "file5.csv" 
#>  [6] "file6.csv"  "file7.csv"  "file8.csv"  "file9.csv"  "file10.csv"
#> [11] "file11.csv" "file12.csv" "file13.csv" "file14.csv" "file15.csv"
#> [16] "file16.csv" "file17.csv" "file18.csv" "file19.csv" "file20.csv"
```

Now we can read the files

```r
lapply(file.path(folder_path, temp), read.csv)
#> [[1]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file1.csv
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file2.csv
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file3.csv
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file4.csv
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file5.csv
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>   X         x
#> 1 1 file6.csv
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: For some reason this returned a list of 289 data frames. perhaps it's the `temp` ? my `temp` is something like this  `[1] "/bigfolder/myname/smallfolder/tFile1.RAW"  "/bigfolder/myname/smallfolder/tFile10.RAW"  
 [3] "/bigfolder/myname/smallfolder/tFile11.RAW"  "/bigfolder/myname/smallfolder/tFile12.RAW" ` and so on

Comment: How many files are you trying to read? can you `dput(temp)` and peste the result here?

Comment: I will reproduce everything in a folder for you, including creating files.

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob I was able to do reproduce all elements in you question and my code worked. If you file path has numbers you might have an error, that is why I'm using `full.names = FALSE` to list files. Let me know if this worked for you.